# Is 'extending' a use case unnecessary when it is directly associated with the actor?

Tags: design, uml, use-case

[image]

I have an Employee who can view items . he also can checkout an item independently (regardless of manage items use-case ).
The problem is that when an Employee view items he can choose to checkout one. So I think one of the following options is true :

1. the 'extend' relation from **view items** to **checkout an item** is not needed and should be deleted
2. the association between the Employee and the **checkout an item** use-case is not needed ( I doubt that one to be true )
3. Options 1 and 2 are wrong . both the association and the 'extend' relation are true and should be there on the diagram.

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem to me. If I am right, please read [this meta post](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) first.

Comment: It's not a homework. it's a question about the UML specification for the 'extend' relation . is it needed even if the actor is directly related to the extending use-case.

Comment: Maybe because of the way I asked the question and the example I gave . I wanted my question to be simple.

Answer (score 3):

If a use case extends another is independent from the visible associations between actors and use cases. However, whenever there is an actor associated with a use case like "checkout items", it is clear this situation requires user interaction, which makes it mandatory to have **a viewing feature part of that use case**, not the other way round.

Therefore, I heavily recommend **not to model "view items" as a use case on its own**. An employee does not view items "just for fun", for real use cases, there should be a business purpose behind it. Some examples, which all will need this viewing feature:

- checking some item properties for the purpose of quality assurance - then the use case is "quality assurance of items"
- given those items have a price, then "paying an item" might be a use case
- "checkout items" (whatever that means in your context, since "checkout" and "item" are generic terms with many different possible meanings)

UML use case notation is intended for describing usage scenarios mostly independend from the UI. This notation and the "extends" and "includes" relationships are designed for a higher level of abstraction. Even if the use case "checkout items" will be started at the user interface by viewing the items first, that is nothing I would try to express through the model, it is just an UI detail.

If you still feeel urged to model "view items" as a separate use case, maybe for exercising purposes, then I would recommend to draw an "includes" relationship from a use case like "checkout items" to "view items". However, it is IMHO obvious that most use cases involving user interaction with items need a viewing feature: users don't want to poke around with items blindly when operating on them.

Comment: `An employee does not view items "just for fun"` -- I always liked the *boss test* for deciding if a UC adds value. I.e., if you told your boss you spent the day "viewing items" (or "logging in", etc.), would she be happy with you?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Not for fun, but probably to gather information for further decisions. But yes, the boss test is also my argument for the login.

Answer (score 0):

This is about semantics of conceptual modeling with use cases.
A lot of model approaches use multiplicity on the association ends in a UC diagram.
But in the simple diagrams these often are ommited, leading to an 1..1 assumption.

An example:
If initiator X starts use case A, which itself  extends to a use case B, the initiating event is the exception point decision. So initiator of use case B still is the initiator X of use case A. 
Now we add, for some strange reason, an initiator Y to use case B. Also with a 1..1 multiplicity on both association ends. Now use case B must have an initiator Y, even in the extend situation!  So 2 initiating actors are needed to complete the use case B functionality. If there is no extend, actor Y can solely start use case B and use all of its functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I would just opt for removing the `<<extends>>`. An actor might view items to maybe get details. So it's a UC on its own. Also he might check out an item. Means he must know the ID of the item in order to check it out. Also a pretty legal UC. Now from a practical view: what is the context? Some clerk in a company might know the ID by heart and just issue a check out. In contrast a normal customer at, say, Amazon will  have a different UC. It would be `browse items`. And eventually he decides to buy an item. In that case the checkout would extend the `browse items`. Since you are talking about an employee it's pretty likely to be the first scenario: no extend needed.